# How to change the active tab color with more than 2 colors in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I need to change the tab icons background color to red in home screen, yellow in the another tab(list)
blue in the another tab (section) while I am clicking on the particular tab

In my app it have three footer tabs.

I need to change color for each tab with different color.
How can I achieve this?

```
const HomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ListScreen,
  HomeScreen,
  SectionScreen,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'red',
    style: {
      paddingTop: 5,
      height: 65
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Go to your tab  code for example 'SectionScreen' and in constructor call navigation from that library/redux and there you will have options for your tab https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#props

Comment: Added the tabBarOptions insie the components

Answer (score 0):

You can set activeBackgroundColor and inactiveBackgroundColor using with [tabBarOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaroptions)
But all tab are the same.

For make different, you have to customize its Tab components.
React Navigation v5 documents for tabBar Props.

Here's doc [tabBar](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar)

```
const MyTabBar = ({state, descriptors, navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
        <Text>One Tab</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
        <Text>Second Tab</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
        <Text>Third Tab</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

And Router file

```
<Tab.Navigator tabBar={props => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>

</Tab.Navigator>
```

**EDIT:**
for react-navigation v3;

```
const TabBarComponent = (props) => (<BottomTabBar {...props} />);
const TabScreens = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    tabBarComponent: props =>
      <TabBarComponent
        {...props}
        style={{ borderTopColor: '#605F60' }}
      />,
  },
);
```

Doc v3 [tabBarComponent](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/bottom-tab-navigator#bottomtabnavigatorconfig)

Comment: I am using react-navigation@3.13.0. Here I need to change the tintcolor of the tabs alone.

Comment: use tabBarOptions or customize your component with tabBarComponent. I edited answer for v3.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
        

    
    const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
   
const BottomTabScreen = () => (        
        <Tab.Navigator activeColor="#fff">
                <Tab.Screen
                  name="Home"
                  initialRouteName="Home"
                  component={HomeScreen}
                  options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
                    tabBarColor: '#3333cc',
                    tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                      <Icon name="ios-home" color={color} size={26} />
                    ),
                  }}
                />
                <Tab.Screen
                  name="Notifications"
                  component={UpdateScreen}
                  options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Updates',
                    tabBarColor: '#196619',
                    tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                      <Icon name="ios-notifications" color={color} size={26} />
                    ),
                  }}
                />
                <Tab.Screen
                  name="Profile"
                  component={ProfileScreen}
                  options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
                    tabBarColor: '#e67300',
                    tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                      <Icon name="ios-person" color={color} size={26} />
                    ),
                  }}
                />
                <Tab.Screen
                  name="Explore"
                  component={ExploreScreen}
                  options={{
                    tabBarLabel: 'Explore',
                    tabBarColor: '#751a2e',
                    tabBarIcon: ({color}) => (
                      <Icon name="ios-aperture" color={color} size={26} />
                    ),
                  }}
                />
              </Tab.Navigator>
    );
    
    export default BottomTabScreen;
```